# DLookup expression always returning the same record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-forms, dlookup

I have a form called `ProductionReportLandscape` that has a table called `ProductMasterData` set as its record source.

There is text box control called `CartonDateFormat` (which gets its value from the `ProductMasterData` table) as well as an unbound text box control on `ProductionReportLandscape`.

Also in the database is a second table called `DateCodes`. Every record in the `DateCodes` table has a field called `OutputDateCode`. `CartonDateFormat` is a numeric value and can be any number 1-36.

I am trying to get the unbound text box control to return the value from `OutputDateCode` that corresponds to `CartonDateFormat` for each record.

For example, if `CartonDateFormat` is 13, then I would like the text box control to display the `OutputDateCode` from record 13 of the `DateCodes` table. If `CartonDateCode` is 14, then I want the text box to display `OutputDateCode` from record 14, etc for every number 1-36.

I have built a `DLookup` expression the control source property for the unbound text box, but it always returns the `OutputDateCode` from the first record regardless of what record is selected.

I cannot figure out how to change the expression in order to achieve the desired result. Any ideas?

```
=DLookUp("OutputDateCode","DateCodes","[CartonDateFormat] =" & [CartonDateFormat])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reference names `CartonDateFormat` and `CartonDateCode`. You indicate CartonDateFormat is a textbox but not what CartonDateCode is.

Unless DateCodes has field CartonDateFormat with carton codes, DLookup cannot find match.

The DLookup needs to use name of field in DateCodes table that has carton codes. If that is CartonDateCode, then change DLookup to:

`=DLookUp("OutputDateCode","DateCodes","[CartonDateCode] =" & [CartonDateFormat])`

Comment: This was very helpful. I misspoke when I said CartonDateCode, it should have been CartonDateFormat. But your example helped me see that the first instance of CartonDateFormat should have been a different field name.